# Doctrine not honoring self-referencing relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-easyadmin

I have a `User` entity with a self-referencing one-to-many relationship - Every `User` owns a set of students (who are also users):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    private $students;

    // ....

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->students = new ArrayCollection();
        // ...
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Remove student
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function removeStudent($student)
    {
        $this->students->removeElement($student);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add a student
     *
     * @param User $students
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addStudent($student)
    {
        $this->students->add($student);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get students
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getStudents()
    {
        $this->students;
    }

    /**
     * Set students
     *
     * @param User $students
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setStudents($students)
    {
        $this->students = $students;

        return $this;
    }
    // ....
}
```

The mapping is done as a [one-to-many unidirectional with join table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:

    // ...

    manyToMany:
      students:
        targetEntity: User
        joinTable:
          name: mentors_students
          joinColumns:
            mentor_id:
              referencedColumnName: id
          inverseJoinColumns:
            student_id:
              referencedColumnName: id
              unique: true              
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Now when I add/edit a user using the EasyAdmin bundle, I can add the students for that user. However, when I retrieve the entity, the students property is always **null**. For example, when I view the list of users:

[image]

Here the user 'sagarl3232' is supposed to be a student of 'sj' but the view above clearly shows the property when retrieved is null.

The entity is **persisted correctly in the database.** That is, the join table has the right values:

[image]

Why is Doctrine doing this to me? Isn't it supposed to hydrate the students array automatically?

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: Did you check (e.g. symfony debug toolbar) whether doctrine issues a correct query when loading that page? Can you reproduce it more isolated, outside EasyAdmin?

Comment: Yes! In fact, doctrine does issue a query to get all the associated students like so: `SELECT ..., u0_.mentor_id AS mentor_id_17 FROM user u0_ WHERE u0_.id IN (?) ORDER BY u0_.id DESC
Parameters: [ 0 => [ 0 => 8, 1 => 7, 2 => 6, 3 => 5, 4 => 1 ] ]`

Comment: @simon.ro As you can see, there are a bunch of parameters are given to fetch the associated users and they are correct as per the database. The ids are different now because I cleared my database and added the users again, but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: @simon.ro I doubt it's a bug with EasyAdmin, because I got null when I tried to fetch the students in my app by doing `$user->getStudents()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter doesnt return anything!

```
/**
 * Get students
 *
 * @return User[]
 */
public function getStudents()
{
    return $this->students;
}
```

BTW why you should adjust the docblock too. The getter is supposed to return an array User[]

Comment: I now have a new problem, I can't edit the students array for a user :/